# Appspot got ERROR 403: Forbidden

Tags: app-store, google-apps, httpforbiddenhandler

We are using appspot as images storage. Last 4 days appspot got "ERROR 403: Forbidden" for our subnet 77.120.117.0/24 (it's not Crimea subnet. It's datacenter in Kiev region).

Service is not available from our servers. How to solve this problem?